# Azure Application Insights Query customDimensions

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I have a Java application that sends log4j2 logs to App Insights. When logging an exception I basically pass a JSON in string format and the exception something like this

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
json.put(...)
....
log.error(json.toString(), exception)
```

On the App Insights side; the message is stored under customDimensions with the key Logger Message in a JSON format.

From this stored information, I would like to make a query that would fetch all the exception messages where the statusCode > 200 and statusCode < 300. I've tried couple of queries but I was not able to extract those specific exception messages.

One of the queries I was trying was

```
exceptions 
| limit 50 
| where toint(customDimensions["Logger Message"].statusCode) > 200 
  and toint(customDimensions["Logger Message"].statusCode) < 300
```

Any help would be appreciated

**Update: I've running the query**

```
exceptions
| limit 50 
| project s1 = customDimensions["Logger Message"]
| extend  s2 = s1.statusCode
| extend  s3 = toint(s2)
| extend  s4 = s3 >= 200 and s3 < 300
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from a query language perspective, you're doing the right thing (assuming you actually want `> 200` and not `>= 200`, so that the query in your example will actually return the record you've pasted a snapshot of)

```
print customDimensions = dynamic({
    "Logger Message":{
        "message":"Test 1 and Test 2",
        "statusCode": 200
    }
})
| project toint(customDimensions['Logger Message'].statusCode)
```

This returns a single table, with a single row, with a single column, with the value `200`.

It's hard to fully understand how the actual data in your case looks like based on the snapshot - you could try 'debugging' it step by step (`s1,...,s4` below) and seeing where it 'breaks'.

- (just a guess) you may need to invoke `parse_json()` on a string payload so that you can actually access dynamic properties in it.

```
exceptions
| limit 50 
| project s1 = customDimensions["Logger Message"]
| extend  s2 = s1.statusCode
| extend  s3 = toint(s2)
| extend  s4 = s3 > 200 and s3 < 300
```

---

**Update:**

try using `parse_json()` as the previous 'guess' suggested:

(plus, see *Notes* section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction)

```
exceptions
| limit 50 
| project s1 = parse_json(tostring(customDimensions["Logger Message"]))
| extend  s2 = s1.statusCode
| extend  s3 = toint(s2)
| extend  s4 = s3 > 200 and s3 < 300
```

Comment: So I tried debugging as per your suggestion and this is what I've updated my post with the image of the output. For some reason; it's not able to return true for s4 irrespective of > or >=. I'm not sure if it recognizes the 200 as an integer

Comment: Actually, I don't think s1.statusCode is returning what it's expected to return

Answer (score 3):

I'm late to the party, but in the Logs query editor results grid you can right-click a field, even in a custom party, and have the query editor adjust your query for you:

[image]

Note that for nullable strings, this will result in a query which compares the string property to `"null"`. This needs to be changed to simply `""`.